# Elasticsearch not sure if filter or query should be first

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using ES for my Laravel app.

What I want to do is a search filtering.

I do a fulltext search on the title field and then check that the price is between 0 - 9999 and that active is set to 1.

But both these queries seems to work fine on my test data. But what is the difference between them? Does the order "query" comes in play any diffrence?

Ignore the syntax, just take a look at the query structure.

**First query**

```
'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
                ],
                'filter'=> [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['term' => [ 'active' =>  1] ],
                            [ 'range' => [
                                    'price' => [
                                        'gte' => 1,
                                        'lte' => 99999,
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
```

**Second query**

```
'filtered' => [
    'filter' => [
      'bool' => [
         'must' => [
            ['term' => [ 'status' =>  1] ], 
            [ 
               'range' => [
                  'price' => [
                      'gte' => 1,
                      'lte' => 99999,
                  ]
               ] 
            ]
         ]               
      ]
  ],
  'query' => [
      'match' => [
        'title' => Input::get('query', '')
      ]
   ]
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference at all in which order `filter` and `query` are mentioned in a `filtered query`. What dictates if `query` or `filter` is executed first for a document depends on an expert-level optional field called `strategy` of `filtered query`. For more information, read [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#_filter_strategy).